# Incorrect result document (presumably) when updating jobs match preferences from reminder widget

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I updated my match preferences to "not interested" from the reminder widget that was shown at the top of the sidebar on the https://stackoverflow.com/jobs landing page, and landed on the following document:

[image: Screenshot]

The status was successfully updated when I check in my profile, the only issue is that I was presented with JSON output instead of a web page (which I assume is the intended result).

I don't have a screenshot of the widget I used to do it as I guess it was some kind of reminder form because I had not changed this setting for a while? The form is no longer shown where it was so I cannot screenshot it. It was in the same place on the page as what is now showing as "Advanced Search Tips".

Updating the setting from the main profile page works as expected.

Using Chrome 52/Win 10.

Comment: Taking a look now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form was supposed to be intercepted with a piece of JS that was failing under certain circumstances. I've just pushed a fix to production that rectifies it. Thanks for the report!